# Printing job error stuck in printer's queue (HP LaserJet 1005/Win10)

Tags: windows-10, printer, hp-laserjet

I accidentally tried to print a PDF document while the printer was off.
As result, there is a printing job with error in queue.
And as result no other printing job can go through.

I tried to cancel the job but it say it has cancellation error or something like that.

I tried this https://www.werockyourweb.com/how-delete-or-cancel-hung-print-jobs-windows/ + reboot but failing printing job stays in queue.

I tried to log in with the administrator account and uninstall the printer and/or drivers but it this crashed the printer management window or at best says the printer is under use.

Comment: you can try: disconnect printer, reboot your pc and uninstall after that.

Comment: Did you close the application that is trying to send the print job?

Comment: Thank you but I already tried both of these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by following this https://www.windowscentral.com/how-remove-stuck-print-job-windows-10
instead of the linked mentioned in the original question.

(The main difference is that the first link tell `NET STOP SPOOLER` in the Run window (Win+R) while the second one tells to run it in command line. And maybe the difference comes from the fast that, pressing Win+R, I didn't even think of "running Win+R as administrator", while in the command line console, I could see `NET STOP SPOOLER` failing and re-open it with administrator rights.)